# Make WGS84 box to fit a circle of radius R

Tags: geodesic, geodesy

Let's assume I have a WGS84 box given by its north-east and south-west latitude and longitude.

I want to make sure that a circle of radius R fits inside that box, i.e. if the box is too small, it should be enlarged to exactly fit the circle.

Comment: So, in other words, you have a fixed circle on the globe, and you want to have the smallest WGS84 box that includes that circle? I don't know anything about geodesics, but is it possible to extract the maximum and minimum latitudes and longitudes of the given circle? You could just use them as the edges of the box ...

Comment: Isn’t the answer just to replace the box with a square of side $2R$ if either of the side lengths is less than $2R$, and otherwise do nothing? Why is let after that?

Comment: Please, give references for "WGS84 box".

Comment: WGS84 pretends the Earth is an ellipsoid.  In this context, what does "circle" mean?